# Set Infopath form Items permission in Nintex WorkFlow

Tags: infopath2010

What i need to do is set permission to custom infopath bunot, so only "Owners" group could see/use it. When Infopath form is saved in library, workflow is stating, and giving the permission. So it should check if the current user is in "Owners" group and if he is, give him permission to see/use this button. 
My question is: how can i get the information of Infopath button using nintex, and how to verify if current user is in right group.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i couldn't finde the information of how to do it in nintex, and not sure that its even possible. What I did was follow [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13271.extracting-user-group-of-current-login-user-in-infopath-2010.aspx) tutorial, and accomplished my goal by using Infopath only. I guess this way is easyer.